# Recognise replacement of """ as 'null' in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have currently just written a query to replace all double quotes across my input data (from a csv file that is pipe delimited but also has double quotes around each column). I am trying to simultaneously coalesce the first column (which is a nvarchar column), but I cannot get my coalesce statement to work as upon removing the double quotes SQL doesn't recognise the column as blank (doesn't come up as NULL).

Would really appreciate any help on what I can do to make SQL recognise that Column1, once rid of "", is now full of blanks and therefore should pull data from columns 2, 3 or 4!

```
Insert Into [mytable] 
Select COALESCE (REPLACE (Column1,'"', ''), REPLACE (Column 2, '"', ''), 
REPLACE (Column3, '"', ''), REPLACE (Column4, '"', ''))
From [datasource]
```

Comment: '' is not null, you are writing empty strings in you columns in stead of null. Try replacing '' with null in your query

Comment: Thanks @GuidoG, this was indeed the issue however some records do have data in them so I simply wanted to remove the quotes, not nullify the whole field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite cumbersome, but you can use `NULLIF` with `LTRIM` and:

```
Select COALESCE (NULLIF(LTRIM(REPLACE (Column1,'"', '')), ''), 
                 REPLACE (Column 2, '"', ''), 
                 REPLACE (Column3, '"', ''), 
                 REPLACE (Column4, '"', ''))
From [datasource]
```

`LTRIM` will remove all the leading white spaces from your string. if it only contains white spaces, `LTRIM` will return an empty string.
`NULLIF` will return `null` if the two arguments passed to is are equal.

My example is only for the first column, use it on the other columns if you need.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert Into [mytable] 
Select NULLIF(COALESCE (REPLACE (Column1,'"', ''), REPLACE (Column 2, '"', ''), 
REPLACE (Column3, '"', ''), REPLACE (Column4, '"', '')),'')
From [datasource]
```

Comment: Thanks - this recognises Column1 as 'null' but does not carry out the coalesce function

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO [mytable] 
SELECT
    CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(COALESCE(Column1, ''), '"', '')) > 0
         THEN REPLACE(COALESCE(Column1, ''), '"', '')
         WHEN LEN(REPLACE(COALESCE(Column2, ''), '"', '')) > 0
         THEN REPLACE(COALESCE(Column2, ''), '"', '')
         CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(COALESCE(Column3, ''), '"', '')) > 0
         THEN REPLACE(COALESCE(Column3, ''), '"', '')
         WHEN LEN(REPLACE(COALESCE(Column4, ''), '"', '')) > 0
         THEN REPLACE(COALESCE(Column4, ''), '"', '')
         ELSE '' END
FROM [datasource]
```

I feel that some of the ugliness of this query is due to your data model.  Ideally you would not be storing doubke quotes at all, just the actual content.  Then, we could just use NULL or empty string to decide which content to insert.

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear - I certainly do not want to store the double quotes! The purpose of the replace is to get rid of them when uploading into my database. However when I use replace to get rid of the double quotes sql doesn't recognise that Column1 is not null - it just shows as a blank - so coalesce doesn't work

Comment: @Sam109 Did you bother to try my answer (or any answer for that matter) ?